# Connectivity loss while sending data

Tags: flutter, dart, connectivity

I'm trying to figure out if there's a way to know if the connection was lost while i was sending data (several documents with photos).
Right now if I suddenly loose the connection, my CircularProgressIndicator() keeps on going. How do I throw an error or set a timeout ?
Sometimes I get  `SocketException: OS Error: Operation timed out, errno = 60, address = ***.com, port = 49434` but not always

Comment: Can you please show us some code ?

Comment: Refer this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55016701/flutter-how-to-check-for-internet-connection

Answer (score 0):

You can catch the error:

```
try {
/// Send your data
} on SocketException {
/// Do something
}
```